# what is the default page setup for landscape in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Please suggest what is the default page setup values (horizontal and vertical in centimeters) for landscape when we install CR in our machine.  I changed my value so I am unable show the report in CR viewer.

Comment: create a new report and you find the `default values` if you go to pagesetup

Comment: vertical & horizontal values will get changed based on paper size. For example: A4 size page will be 297x210mm in size. You can attain the default values by change the "paper size" under page setup option.

Comment: Do you mean the page's height and width or the size of the margins?

Comment: Hi Craig height and width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A4](http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm) is defined to be 210mm (width) x 297mm (height).  In landscape, that would be 297mm x 210mm.

In Crystal Reports:

[image]

That would make the printable area 118mm (210-46-46) x 213mm (297-42-42).

Comment: Hi Craig Please suggest for landscape